# Sun Shadow Volume Tool ESRI

Tags: arcgis-desktop, volume, shadow

At my ***Sun Shadow Volume*** analysis I have the problem that not all of the shadow volumes reach the originating feature.

I get a field named "**HUGS_FEATR**" where it is indicated if the shadow hugs the feature or not.

But of course I need every shadow to "hug" the feature!

I´m using ArcGIS Desktop Advanced!

Any suggestions?

EDIT(1):
I found out that this problem just exists when I have a DEM as Base Height set. BUT this DEM is just a flat Raster with exactly 200 metres above sea level (1m x 1m). Without setting a Base Hight and just extruding the feature (building) the tool seems to work like a charm! Strange..

Comment: Which product from the ArcGIS platform are you using to try and do this?

Comment: I´m using ArcGIS Desktop Advanced!

Comment: I found out that this problem just exists when I have a DEM as Base Height set. BUT this DEM is just a flat Raster with exactly 200 metres above sea level (1m x 1m). Without setting a Base Hight and just extruding the feature (building) the tool seems to work like a charm! Strange...

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information that you think may help attract a potential answerer to it. That will help its chances of being re-opened too.